# Applying "percentage of group total" to a column in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I generate another dataframe using following code as under:

```
df.groupby(['Cat','Ans']).agg({'col1':'count','col2':'sum'})
```

This gives me following result:

```
Cat  Ans  col1    col2
A    Y    100     10000.00
     N    40      15000.00
B    Y    80      50000.00
     N    40      10000.00
```

Now, I need percentage of group totals for each group (level=0, i.e. "Cat") instead of count or sum.

For getting count percentage instead of count value, I could do this:

```
df['Cat'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

But here I have sub-group "Ans" under the "Cat" group. And I need the percentage to be on each Cat group level and not the whole total.

So, expectation is:

```
Cat  Ans  col1    ..    col3
A    Y    100     ..    71.43  #(100/(100+40))*100
     N    40      ..    28.57
B    Y    80      ..    66.67
     N    40      ..    33.33
```

Similarly, col4 will be percentage of group-total for col2.

Is there a function or method available for this?
How do we do this in an efficient way for large data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `level` argument of DataFrame.sum (to perform a `groupby`) and have pandas take care of the index alignment for the division.

```
df['col3'] = df['col1']/df['col1'].sum(level='Cat')*100

         col1     col2       col3
Cat Ans                          
A   Y     100  10000.0  71.428571
    N      40  15000.0  28.571429
B   Y      80  50000.0  66.666667
    N      40  10000.0  33.333333
```

---

For multiple columns you can loop the above, or have pandas align those too. I add a suffix to distinguish the new columns from the original columns when joining back with `concat`.

```
df = pd.concat([df, (df/df.sum(level='Cat')*100).add_suffix('_pct')], axis=1)

         col1     col2   col1_pct   col2_pct
Cat Ans                                     
A   Y     100  10000.0  71.428571  40.000000
    N      40  15000.0  28.571429  60.000000
B   Y      80  50000.0  66.666667  83.333333
    N      40  10000.0  33.333333  16.666667
```

Comment: That's pretty neat!